# What is the return type of a multi-valued function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

The most commonly used definition is as follows: "A multifunction is a mapping between $D$ and $\mathcal{P}(E)$, where $D$ and $E$ are some sets." However, the following notations are commonly used: $f(1)=2$ (where $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and, for example, $f(1)$ is $\{1, 2, 3\}$), $f(1)+3=5$, and so on.
If $f$ returns a subset of reals, wouldn't that imply that, technically, $\{1, 2, 3\}=2$? So the operator $=$ is defined differently if the types on the left- and right-hand sides differ?
Or maybe $f$ returns not a set, but a more complex structure, something like a tuple?

Comment: I'm trying to understand here. Are you saying that you might write "$f(1) = 2$" just because $2 \in f(1)$? The solution is to not write that: it's confusing notation.

Comment: @S.C. I meant that it's commonly written like that (for example, arg(1+i)=9pi/4). I want to understand the notation, because, in my mind, arg(1+i) returns a set of complex numbers, not just one, and it's confusing to me that a set=a number.

Comment: I agree with @S.C.: if it's really the intention to have the values of a function be sets, then that's their value, not any one element of the set. Whenever we write something like $\arg(1+i)=\frac{9\pi}4$, that should be in the context of having chosen one particular branch of the multivalued function (in other words, in that discussion changing a multivalued function into an actual single-valued function).